# Removing unique elements in a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I need a little help removing unique characters in a doubly linked list in C. So here's the logic I tried implementing: I counted the occurrence of each character in the doubly linked list. If it's occurrence is 1 time, then it is unique element and needs to be deleted. I'll be repeating the process for all elements. But my code in remove_unique_dll() function isn't working properly, please help me fix it. Here's my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct node *head, *tail = NULL; //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list  
int len;

void addNode(char data)
{
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Create new node  
    newNode->data = data;

    if (head == NULL)
    {      //If dll is empty  
        head = tail = newNode;  //Both head and tail will point to newNode  
        head->prev = NULL; //head's previous will point to NULL  
        tail->next = NULL; //tail's next will point to NULL, as it is the last node of the list  
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode; //newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next points to newNode  
        newNode->prev = tail; //newNode's previous will point to tail  
        tail = newNode;  //newNode will become new tail  
        tail->next = NULL; //As it is last node, tail's next will point to NULL  
    }
}

void remove_unique_dll()
{
    struct node *current = head;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int cnt;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        cnt = 1;

        //printf("!%c ",next->data);

        while (next != NULL)
        {
            if (next->data == current->data)
            {
                cnt += 1;
                next = next->next;
            }
            else
                next = next->next;

            //printf("@%c %d %c\n",next->data,cnt,current->data);
        }

        if (cnt == 1)
        {
            prev = current->prev;
            //printf("@%c %d",prev->data,cnt);

            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                head = next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = next;
            }

            if (next == NULL)
            {
                tail = prev;
            }
            else
            {
                next->prev = prev;
            }

        }
        current = current->next;
        //printf("#%c ",current->data);
    }

    head = current;
}

void display()
{
    struct node *current = head;  //head the global one

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c<->", current->data); //Prints each node by incrementing pointer.  
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    int i;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    len = strlen(s);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        addNode(s[i]);
    }

    printf("Doubly linked list: \n");
    display();

    remove_unique_dll();

    printf("Doubly linked list after removing unique elements: \n");
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is like this-
[image]

If you uncomment the printf() statements inside remove_unique_dll() you'll notice that no code below inner while loop is being executed after inner while loop ends. What's the issue here and what's the solution?

Sample input- aacb

Expected output- a<->a<->NULL

Comment: Do not display text only as images. It cannot readily be copied by others to paste into the program as input or read aloud by software for vision-impaired users. You can copy the text and paste it into the question between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to display “preformatted” text.

Comment: Is the expected output `a<->a<->NULL` or `a<->NULL` or something else? A [mre] always includes a sample of expected output or description of the desired behavior.

Comment: If the loop is not broken in some other manner `while (current != NULL) { /* ... */ }` followed by `head = current` is always going to "empty" the list.

Comment: @Oka then can you please tell me how do I assign modified doubly linked list to head? Or at least print modified doubly linked list without assigning to head?

Comment: When I run the code and enter `foobarbaz`, the program crashes because of a NULL pointer access in `remove_unique_dll`. Your loop `while (current != NULL)` will always end with `current == NULL`; so at the end of the function you will always assign `head = NULL`. Of course an assignment to `head` might make sense if you want to remove the first node. Indenting the code properly helps to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You shouldn't assign `head = current` at the end, because by then `current` is `NULL`
- The `next` you use in the deletion part is not the successor of `current`, so this will make wrong links
- As you progress through the list, every value is going to be regarded as unique at some point: when it is the *last* occurrence, you'll not find a duplicate anymore, as your logic only looks ahead, not backwards.
- When you remove a node, you should free its memory.
- Not a big issue, but there is no reason to really **count** the number of duplicates. Once you find the first duplicate, there is no reason to look for another.

You should really isolate the different steps of the algorithm in separate functions, so you can debug and test each of those features separately and also better understand your code.

Also, to check for duplicates, you might want to use the following fact: if the first occurrence of a value in a list is the same node as the last occurrence of that value, then you know it is unique. As your list is doubly linked, you can use a backwards traversal to find the last occurrence (and a forward traversal to find the first occurrence).

Here is some suggested code:

```
struct node* findFirstNode(char data) {
    struct node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
}

struct node* findLastNode(char data) {
    struct node *current = tail;
    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
        current = current->prev;
    }
    return current;
}

void removeNode(struct node *current) {
    if (current->prev == NULL) {
        head = current->next;
    } else {
        current->prev->next = current->next;
    }
    if (current->next == NULL) {
        tail = current->prev;
    } else {
        current->next->prev = current->prev;
    }
    free(current);
}

void remove_unique_dll() {  
    struct node *current = head;
    struct node *next;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        if (findFirstNode(current->data) == findLastNode(current->data)) {
            removeNode(current);
        }
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three errors.

After counting the number of occurrences of an item, you use `next` in several places. However, `next` has been used to iterate through the list. It was moved to the end and is now a null pointer. You can either reset it with `next = current->next;` or you can change the places that use `next` to `current->next`.

At the end of `remove_unique_dll`, you have `head=current;`. There is no reason to update `head` at this point. Whenever the first node was removed from the list, earlier code in `remove_unique_dll` updated `head`. So it is already updated. Delete the line `head=current;`.

That will leave code that deletes all but one occurrence of each item. However, based on your sample output, you want to leave multiple occurrences of items for which there are multiple occurrences. For that, you need to rethink your logic in `remove_unique_dll` about deciding which nodes to delete. When it sees the first `a`, it scans the remainder of the list and sees the second, so it does not delete the first `a`. When it sees the second `a`, it scans the remainder of the list and does not see a duplicate, so it deletes the second `a`. You need to change that.

Comment: One way fix the problem with deleting the last duplicate would be to move deleted nodes to a local list that can be searched in addition to searching the remainder of the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider your code step by step.

It seems you think that in this declaration

```
struct node *head, *tail = NULL; //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
```

the both pointers `head` and `tail` are explicitly initialized by `NULL`. Actually only the pointer `tail` is explicitly initialized by `NULL`. The pointer `head` is initialized implicitly as a null pointer only due to placing the declaration in file scope. It to place such a declaration in a block scope then the pointer `head` will be uninitialized.

Instead you should write

```
struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL; //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
```

Also it is a very bad approach when the functions depend on these global variables. In this case you will be unable to have more than one list in a program.

Also the declaration of the variable `len` that is used only in main as a global variable

```
int len;
```

also a bad idea. And moreover this declaration is redundant.

You need to define one more structure that will contain pointers `head` and `tail` as data members as for example

```
struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};
```

The function `addNode` can invoke undefined behavior when a new node can not be allocated

```
void addNode(char data)
{
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Create new node  
    //...
```

You should check whether a node is allocated successfully and only in this case change its data members. And you should report the caller whether a node is created or not.

So the function should return an integer that will report an success or failure.

In the function `remove_unique_dll` after this while loop

```
    while (next != NULL)
    {
        if (next->data == current->data)
        {
            cnt += 1;
            next = next->next;
        }
        else
            next = next->next;

        //printf("@%c %d %c\n",next->data,cnt,current->data);
    }
```

if cnt is equal to 1

```
    if (cnt == 1)
    //..
```

then the pointer `next` is equal to `NULL`. And using the pointer `next` after that like

```
        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            head = next;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = next;
        }
```

is wrong.

Also you need to check whether there is a preceding node with the same value as the value of the current node. Otherwise you can remove a node that is not a unique because after it there are no nodes with the same value.

And this statement

```
head = current;
```

does not make sense because after the outer while loop

```
while (current != NULL)
```

the pointer `current` is equal to `NULL`.

Pay attention that the function will be more useful for users if it will return the number of removed unique elements.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the list and the function `remove_unique_dll` can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

int addNode( struct list *list, char data )
{
    struct node *node = malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = list->tail;

        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = node;
        }

        list->tail = node;
    }

    return success;
}

size_t remove_unique_dll( struct list *list )
{
    size_t removed = 0;

    for ( struct node *current = list->head; current != NULL; )
    {
        struct node *prev = current->prev;

        while (prev != NULL && prev->data != current->data)
        {
            prev = prev->prev;
        }

        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            //  there is no preceding node with the same value
            //  so the current node is possibly unique

            struct node *next = current->next;
            while (next != NULL && next->data != current->data)
            {
                next = next->next;
            }

            if (next == NULL)
            {
                // the current node is indeed unique

                struct node *to_delete = current;
                if (current->prev != NULL)
                {
                    current->prev->next = current->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    list->head = current->next;
                }

                if (current->next != NULL)
                {
                    current->next->prev = current->prev;
                }
                else
                {
                    list->tail = current->prev;
                }

                current = current->next;

                free( to_delete );

                ++removed;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    return removed;
}

void display( const struct list *list )
{
    for (const node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        printf( "%c<->", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main()
{
    struct list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    const char *s = "aabc";

    for (const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        addNode( &list,  *p );
    }

    printf( "Doubly linked list:\n" );
    display( &list );

    size_t removed = remove_unique_dll( &list );

    printf( "There are removed %zu unique value(s) in the list.\n", removed );

    printf( "Doubly linked list after removing unique elements:\n" );
    display( &list );
}
```

The program output is

```
Doubly linked list:
a<->a<->b<->c<->null
There are removed 2 unique value(s) in the list.
Doubly linked list after removing unique elements:
a<->a<->null
```

You will need at least to write one more function that will free all the allocated memory when the list will not be required any more.